# Diagrams of a Summer

Tags: word, visual, knowledge

My friend was being cryptic about how he spent his summer. I was prying, so he gave me two oval-shaped diagrams and told me I could figure it out, at least before next summer. However, I'm lazy and I want to crowd-source the puzzle.

[image][image]

In what activity did my friend spend his summer?

Hint:

> My friend said he used a nonstandard pronunciation of the activity

Hint 2:

> [image]

Comment: Is he one of those map maker people

Comment: @Duck No, he did not spend his summer making maps, he just gave me these two as a puzzle

Comment: Oh, ok, back to the drawing board

Comment: @Duck You were talking about *making maps* and now you've headed back to the *drawing board*. Was that an intended joke? :P

Comment: Oh, actually, no

Answer (score 1):

I think your friend was

> Fingerpainting. This is because the shapes are ovals and the tips of your fingers make an oval shape when you press them down on something like when your pressing a button. There seems to be lines of paint or ink on the ovals which suggests that your friend may have painted their fingers and pressed them against pieces of papers in ovals to give you.

Hint 1

> The designs look strange and don't look very pretty or anything so people would consider this a nonstandard pronunciation of fingerpainting.

Hint 2

> That's the splotch of ink or paint that your friend used to paint their fingers.

Comment: No, this is not it. Interesting takes on the hints though.