# $1 = \rm Square. 2 =\:?$

Tags: rebus

*Inspired by @[R.D](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51604/r-d)'s [quick rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71105/a-quick-rebus-puzzle). Make sure to check that out if you haven't already!*

---

Here is a Rebus Puzzle I made. Hope you enjoy! And I hope it isn't too easy...

[image: REBUS]

Also, the title is a clue.

**Hint:**

> I like *drawing*. I don't get *bored* of it.

---

**Edit:**

One of the comments below [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70683/diagrams-of-a-summer) had to subconsciously be my inspiration...

Comment: Ayyy nicely done!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is the answer to this

> Back to the Drawing Board? (Back + 2 + the Drawing Board)

Comment: Yeee, I'm not good at Rebuses, hahah :P

Comment: Did you draw that yourself, @user477343? It's still better than what I could put together!

Comment: Yeah I did. I thought it would be funny that I *drew* it myself. Wanna have a go at explaining the title? I'm sure you'd get it :D

Comment: (+1) from me, you get my upvote for your hard work! :D

Comment: Hahah, drawing the circle for the head was the hardest part :P

Comment: I don't think I'd have been as accurate as you with that, compass or not! :P

Comment: El-Guest, you're quick on these rebus puzzles! +1

Comment: Oh woops. Jesus Christ, I keep forgetting to do this: $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ ..... maybe because I am busy doing another rebus! :D